# protect tikz/math function from pgfplots expansion?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there some way to combine the following fantastic tools ?

- tikz/math functions *"executing code outside the parser"*
- pgfplots

What I have tried is the following :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myStyle/.style = {fill = white, text = blue,}, every node/.style = myStyle ]
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:4,]
    \addplot[]{x};

    \tikzmath
    {
      \a = 2 ;
      {
        \node at (axis cs: \a,\a) {this is ok} ; 
      };
      function test(\variable)
      {
        {
          \node at (axis cs: \variable,\variable) {but this fails !} ; 
          \node at (axis cs: \a,\a) {also this fails : \variable} ; 
        };
      };
      %test(3); % --- how do I protect my tikz/math function from pgfplots ?
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*(Uncomment the `%test(3)` line to have the code fail.)*

And the call to the `test` function fails, as `\variable` is unrecognized by Pgfplots...

So presumably, something goes wrong in the way the `\node` statement is expanded ?

Cheers,

Comment: put everything in `\pgfplotsextra{}`? Note that you are not doing math but faking it as if it is a math function there are better ways to perform these parametric drawings such as /.pic etc. There is no reason for tikzmath to support this

Comment: Thanks : `\pgfplotsextra{}` works ! It's true I am not doing math, I just like the `function` syntax a lot. I will look into the tikz /.pic

Comment: @percusse Perhaps you should post you comment as the answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.